# Applescript for safari to click downloads

Tags: events, safari, keyboard, applescript

I have been trying to write some applescript that checks to see if the Downloads window is open in Safari and if it is to click and open the last file in the list which is the last file that was downloaded but have been having some issues using Accessibility Inspector I get the following :

```
<AXApplication: "Safari">
 <AXWindow: "Downloads">
  <AXScrollArea>
   <AXList>
    <AXGroup: "ExcelTest.xls">
     <AXButton: "file icon">
Attributes:
   AXRole:  "AXButton"
   AXRoleDescription:  "button"
   AXHelp:  "Open"
   AXFocused:  "false"
   AXParent:  ""
   AXWindow:  ""
   AXTopLevelUIElement:  ""
   AXPosition:  "x=1062 y=396"
   AXSize:  "w=32 h=32"
   AXDescription:  "file icon"`
   AXEnabled:  "true"
Actions:
      AXPress - press
```

I'm not sure how to access the scroll area and list to get at the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
set downloadsIsFrontmost to false
tell application "Safari"
    set theWindows to name of windows
    if (item 1 of theWindows) is "Downloads" then
        activate
        set downloadsIsFrontmost to true
    end if
end tell

if downloadsIsFrontmost then
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Safari"
            set theGroups to groups of list 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Downloads"
            set lastGroup to last item of theGroups
            repeat 2 times
                click button 1 of lastGroup
                delay 0.05
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end if
```

Comment: Thanks, my issue was that I was using tell application "Safari" instead of process so the script I had written wasn't recognizing groups or scroll area as it should. Thanks for clearing that up.